# How to listen to termination app in java?

Tags: java

Is there any possible way listen to a kill signal in a console application?
Is it possible to send message to user just before it stops?

Comment: What is "termination press button"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))

```
public class JVMShutdownHookTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JVMShutdownHook jvmShutdownHook = new JVMShutdownHook();
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(jvmShutdownHook);
    System.out.println("JVM Shutdown Hook Registered.");
    System.out.println("Pre exit.");
    System.exit(0);
    System.out.println("Post exit.");
  }

  private static class JVMShutdownHook extends Thread {
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("JVM Shutdown Hook: Thread initiated.");
    }
  }
}

Output:
JVM Shutdown Hook Registered.
Pre exit.
JVM Shutdown Hook: Thread initiated.
```

Read more [here](http://javapapers.com/core-java/jvm-shutdown-hook/)

Comment: Some more details would be nice.

Comment: @Piarix, kindly accept the answer as it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Thread)`, to run some code before JVM shutdown process...

Answer (score 0):

You can use native code for it like described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2357/Console-Event-Handling)